How can rebirth occur without sex & parents?
I read the following on the internet:

The birth that is going to take place, by which I mean the past life
of the being that is going to take another birth, will do so
regardless of one deciding to have children or not.

Now I have read in the suttas & Visuddhimagga certain actions respectively lead to the respective godly, human, animal, ghost & hell realms. The Visuddhimagga appears to explain how only spontaneous birth in certain heavens & hells has no physical component. Thus spontaneous birth (opapātika) is often defined as 'birth without parents'.
Therefore, if many people chose to follow the Noble Eightfhold Path and be celibate, how will the past life beings (destined by their kamma for the human world) be reborn if there is a limited supply of embryos? Will there be more twins, triplets, etc? What do various Buddhist texts say about this question?


OP: Therefore, if many people chose to follow the Noble Eightfhold Path
and be celibate, how will the past life beings (destined by their
kamma for the human world) be reborn if there is a limited supply of
embryos? Will there be more twins, triplets, etc? What do various
Buddhist texts say about this question?

It's the other way round. Most people will not choose to follow the Noble Eightfold Path.

“I’ve struggled hard to realize this,
enough with trying to explain it!
Those mired in greed and hate
can’t really understand this teaching.
It goes against the stream, subtle,
deep, obscure, and very fine.
Those besotted by greed cannot see,
for they’re shrouded in a mass of darkness.”
SN 6.1


“What do you think, Ānanda? Which is harder and more challenging: to
shoot arrows from a distance through a small keyhole, shot after shot
without missing? Or to take a horsehair split into seven strands and
penetrate one tip with another tip?”
“It’s more difficult and challenging, sir, to take a horsehair split
into seven strands and penetrate one tip with another tip.”
“Still, Ānanda, those who truly penetrate suffering, its origin, its
cessation, and the path penetrate something tougher than that.
SN 56.45


Blind is the world;
here only a few possess insight.
Only a few,
like
birds escaping from the net,
go to realms of bliss.
Dhp 174



Therefore, if many people chose to follow the Noble Eightfhold Path and be celibate,

It's impossible 100%. If you do follow Pa-Auk Tawya every step, you will know "there are surely that very few people can do and done following the Buddha, even they try it hard".
You think like that because you never try to practice hard enough like Pa-Auk Tawya.
Basically, even you just recollection back the past lives then you can see that there never be "many people [in every universes] chose to follow the Noble Eightfhold Path [together]". And the Pali Canon also said "there is only one Buddha each time".

how will the past life beings (destined by their kamma for the human world) be reborn if there is a limited supply of embryos? Will there be more twins, triplets, etc? What do various Buddhist texts say about this question?

There are infinity embryos in the trillion universes and now the scientist just can't understand even one universe.
It is in Visuddhimagga which you told us "Now I have read in the suttas & Visuddhimagga".
And I can tell you that I didn't touch Visuddhimagga maybe for a year. Why I can answer the question of one who said  "Now I have read in the suttas & Visuddhimagga".
Hardly Practice and Memorizing are what the readers forgotten then they can't answer themselves even the simple questions of what they've read.

Also this answer did not answer the question. The question is "How can rebirth occur without sex & parents?" Your answer about infinite trillions of embryos implies there are trillions of sexual acts.

Also, the question asks: "What do various Buddhist texts say about this question?". Your answer did not include any  Buddhist text quotes. Your answer sounded like only your personal opinion. Regards

I've answered  because the question's context is not only what the author distort his own answer. And I've quoted the texts already. It depends on the reader's skill to see the quotes. If the reader heart is not "skillful", the eyes of readers are blind, not mine. If one acts like a professor, he should claims and access insight like a professor too. Read Sutta carefully, Kamma, Metta ^.^

No text quoted anywhere.

the Visuddhimagga on the internet includes a footnote by the translator that says: "Cakkavá¿a (world-sphere or universe) is a term for the concept of a single complete
universe as one of an infinite number of such universes. ". Its only a footnote. You should quote exactly where the Visuddhimagga (which is not Buddha's teaching) refers to what you are trying to say.


Will there be more twins, triplets, etc?

No.
That's because Karma doesn't unfold if there's no availability of a suitable situation/surroundings. Karma isn't the only reason for rebirth in a specific realm.

how will the past life beings (destined by their kamma for the human world) be reborn if there is a limited supply of embryos?

They (the ones who have less potential to be born among humans) get born in another realm(God, Asura, etc.) unlit a place among humans is available.
There are more planes of existing than just humans.
If there's not enough place(parents, etc.) in the human realm, those beings will born among Animals (birds, fish, ants, etc.), Asura, Gods, Naga, etc.
And there's no requirement of parents or sex to be born among Asura, Gods, etc.

Example:- It's said, that when the world gets destroyed at the end of this Kalpa, all the beings that live below the Abassara Brahma realm, die and are born in the Abassara Brahma realm. When this happens, a lot of hell realms, the human realm, the animal realm, and God realms get destroyed and all the beings who lived there get born in the Abassara Brahma realm temporarily.
This happens because, there's no place for them to be born, and live; because their worlds get destroyed.
Once those worlds get built and available, those beings get born in appropriate realms according to their Karma.
The only exception is, that beings who have very very bad Karma, don't go to this Abassara Brahma world. When hell realms get destroyed they lived in, those beings get born in the hell of another Earth system outside of this. (that doesn't get destroyed simultaneously and is available to be born).
